# I accidentally didn't use std::ref - what does the code do as a result?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I was dealing with my code suddenly allocating lots of memory, and trying to find the source of the problem. The code in question is pretty simple, but I noticed that in the threads created with this function:

```
void ParallelExpandBucket(openData d, const std::unordered_set<uint64_t> &states, int myThread, int totalThreads)
```

I was creating the threads without the `std::ref`:

```
threads.push_back(new std::thread(ParallelExpandBucket, d, states, x, numThreads));
```

What actually happens here as a result?

My guess is that my data is getting copied into the thread constructor and then from there a reference is being passed to `ParallelExpandBucket`. So, this would explain the memory blow-up.

Is this correct, or is something else going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. The call to `ExpandBucket` gets a reference to a copy of `states` that exists as long as the instance of `std::thread` does. Parameters are taken by value, so that means making a copy.

In many cases where you used to need `std::ref` prior to c++11, you no longer do, thanks to perfect forwarding. For example, in calls to `std::make_shared`. However, in this case (as in `std::bind`), having a reference used automatically would be a huge problem because it would blow up if `states` wasn't guaranteed to exist as long as the thread does, and the thread would be unhappy if the thing it had a reference to ceased to exist.

Comment: Thanks -- I suspected that is what was going on, but wasn't sure of the exact mechanism/explanation behind it. I seem to recall getting errors for not using `std::ref` in the past, but I don't remember the exact context.

Comment: @NathanS. You can get errors if you don't use `std::ref` on uncopyable objects in a context where without `std::ref`, they'd have to be copied. That's always with `std::thread` and `std::bind`, and pre-C++11 on things like `std::make_shared`.)

Comment: "if `states` wasn't guaranteed to exist" `std::ref` doesn't magically make your objects last longer though; it's still your responsibility.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Right. If you use `std::ref`, you're promising to keep the object around as long as it's needed. The point is, if `std::thread` or `std::bind` magically added `std::ref` for you the way `std::make_shared` (sort of) does, lots of pre-C++11 code that worked fine before would suddenly break, and you'd need some way to specify that you need a copy in the cases where you do.

Comment: Or, could just use universal references, `forward_as_tuple` and let the programmer worry about the function signature instead of how to pass the arguments. Wouldn't need explicit copy or ref if it was like that. Unless you wanted to force a `const&` to be a copy I guess.